# query to fetch same row by different words in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I am new be in database programming .I have to fetch same  row from different where word for example  I have 2 column keywords and data in keywords there may be more than one words Profit ,profits,revenue  but data column have only one entry

**keywords**                             **data**

Profit, Profits, revenue         It is increasing

Now when user enter profit or profits or revenue then he/she get same data " It increasing"

Could you provide me query .
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use [LIKE](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#like): `SELECT data FROM table WHERE keywords LIKE '%Profit%';`